# Order of the destructor calls at the end of block\program

Tags: c++, destructor

So at the end of the block\program the compiler calls on it's own the destructors for the objects that were defined. Is there a particular order in which the destructors are called?

```
class Foo1{
public:
~Foo1 () {cout << "Foo1 DTOR" << endl;}
};
class Foo2{
public:
~Foo2 () {cout << "Foo2 DTOR" << endl;}
};
void main(){
Foo1 A;
Foo2 B;
}
```

running this program I had the output:

`Foo2 DTOR`

`Foo1 DTOR`

Is it how it always works starting from the last defined object and ending with the first one? Or this behavior ca not be predicted and my output is something particular to this situation?

Comment: Yes, that's generally how things work. The exception would be a collection that can only be traversed in one direction (e.g., singly linked list) in which case the objects it contains are destroyed in the order they were created.

Comment: Why does it matter what order they are called in? Is this just curiosity?

Comment: A duplicate of many: search for [:C++] destructor order

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yes, because I just read how it works for derived objects when this question arise.

Comment: Similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595283/order-and-point-of-calling-destructor?rq=1

Comment: It's the LIFO principle of stack-like memory you observe.

Comment: @Pixelchemist that's what I assumed too, but wasn't sure and unfortunately didn't take enough time to google a bit more the question (or mb googled it wrong)

Comment: I think it is very important to point out what @Pixelchemist, which is the reasoning behind it. As the stack pointer winds down, destructors are calledin the reverse order (how they incremented the stack). Always. Then, any heap memory is destroyed in the order determined by program execution. There is undefined behavior around exceptions in destructors, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIFO ordering for object lifetimes is the only thing that makes sense. Consider this moderately representative example:

```
struct ValueHolder
{
    int value;
    ValueHolder() : value(0) { }
    ~ValueHolder() { std::cout << "Value = " << value << "\n"; }
};

struct HolderGuard
{
    ValueHolder & h;
    HolderGuard(ValueHolder & vh) : vh(h) { }
    ~HolderGuard() { ++h.value; }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    ValueHolder h;
    HolderGuard(h);
}
```

This will first increment the held value, and then print it. It would be impossible for later things to depend on earlier things if the later things weren't destroyed first.

(The beauty of the example construction is that it does the right thing even when later code throws an exception.)

Answer (score 4):

Destructors are always run in the reverse order to constructors (except dynamic memory where programmer explicitly deletes objects in memory (with calling it's destructor)).

In you example A is places before B, so it's constructor called earlier. That's why it's destructor was called after B's destructor.